# Homeomorphic images of endpoints of the Cantor set.

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

A Cantor set is a homeomorphic image of the standard ternary Cantor set $T$. Suppose that we have a Cantor set $C$ on the plane. It is well know that $C$ is in fact ambiently homeomorphic to $T$, meaning that the homeomorphism $h:C\to T$ extends to a homeomorphism of the entire plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**My question is:** Suppose that $E$ is the set of endpoints of the removed intervals in the construction of $T$. Is there a property that points in $C$ must satisfy so that they get mapped to points in $E$ under $h$? In other words given a point in $C$ can someone tell, before knowing where it gets mapped under $h$, whether it will get mapped to an endpoint or not?

If the answer is no in general is there any property we could impose on any point in $C$ so that it would be impossible for it to get mapped to a point in $E$ under $h$?

**Added later:**
For example if the Cantor set $T$ lies on the real line then a point of $T$ that can be approximated by both sides from points in $T$ cannot get mapped by $h$ to a point in $E$ since those points can be approximated only by one side by points in $C$.

Answer (score 2):

The Cantor set is countable dense homogeneous, so we can map the endpoints of the ternary Cantor set to any countable dense subset of a Cantor set.

Comment: I did not know that the Cantor set has this property. So this means that if I have a Cantor set on $\mathbb{R}$ and a dense subset whose points can be approximated by both   directions then that subset is necessarily uncountable. I suppose that answers my fist question in the sense that there is no special property that such points must satisfy. You can just take any dense and countable subset of C. However what about properties that force points to not get mapped to endpoints (like the one I gave)?

Comment: Is it clear that the endpoints can always be mapped on a countable dense subset by an homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^2$? This is false for $\Bbb R^n$, $n\geq 3$

Comment: Any reference for that @AlessandroCodenotti?

Comment: There are Cantor sets embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ with no ambient homeomorphism at all between them, Antoine's necklace and the middle-third one (embedded on an axis in the obvious way say) for example. In $\Bbb R^2$ we know that if $C_1,C_2$ are Cantor sets then there is an ambient homeomorphism between them, but it's not clear to me wheter every homeomorphism of $C_1$ and $C_2$ extends to one of the plane

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Yes that is true. In fact every homeomorphism between  two compact and totally disconnected sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ extends to the whole plane.

Comment: @MadMax that's very interesting, do you have a reference where I can read the proof by any chance?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti See Edwin Moise, Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3, Chapter 13